# How to remove Hyphen in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have to Remove Hyphen in some cases in stored procedure.For example LanguageScore is 1 and Description is Excellent.In that case i want the answer 1-Excellent.But in somecases,for eg: LanguageScore is 2 and no Description for 2.At that time i want the answer like 2.How can i solve this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_getLanguageScores]  
AS  

SELECT       
 [LanguageScoreID],  
 [LanguageScore] + ' - ' + [Description]AS [LanguageScore]  
FROM          
 [M_LanguageScores]  
WHERE   
 [Status] > 0   
ORDER BY   
 [SortOrder]   

SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: You should definitely be doing this kind of presentation logic client side

Comment: I think, you need it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     
    [LanguageScoreID],
     ( CASE 
           WHEN [LanguageScore]= ''
              THEN [Description]
           WHEN [Description]=''
              THEN [LanguageScore]
           ELSE [LanguageScore] + ' - ' + [Description]
       END )AS [LanguageScore] 
FROM        
    [M_LanguageScores]
```